# How can i produce a select handle by css

Tags: css, selection, border, resize

I want to produce a sort of select/resiz border when some on click on the div, and when i move mouse over that the cursor should change accordingly. I want the user to be able to drag the element border and the element re-size accordingly

thanks....

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with pure CSS. You would have to use JavaScript. I suggest checking out a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Have a look to this jQuery plugin:

- [Resizable Plugin Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not something which CSS can do by itself. Javascript is needed to do this sort of behaviour.

If you want to implement this, take a look at the Resizeable function of the jQuery UI library. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable

Comment: You beat me by 7 seconds with the same answer with the same link :) +1

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for CSS. CSS is (mostly) for styling only, not functionality.

Check for example the [JQuery resizable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/). It should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this isn't something that can be accomplished by CSS, which is presentation only. Have a look at Yahoo's excellent YUI library and their *Resize Utility*, here is an example:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/resize/simple_resize.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice demo of using jQuery to do what you are looking for.  It uses the [jQuery Resizing](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable) with images CSS and a few other things.  Take a look at [Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)